# Fancybox thumbnails not working

Tags: javascript, php, fancybox, thumbnails

Im having some problems with the fancybox thumbnails. What Im doing is calling a fancybox gallery with the thumbnails helper from a fancybox iframe. I dont know if this is the problem, but I cant seem to make the thumbnails appear. They do show in a media gallerie I have. but not on the normal gallery. Im using a php loop to put each of the images. Here is the code.
This is what I have for each of the Iframe(.various) the gallery(fancybox-thumb) and for the media player with thumb helpers(fancybox-media)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 400,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterClose  :   function() {
            var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
            if (name == 'folder 1') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }
            if (name == 'folder 2') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb2').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }
            if (name == 'folder 3') {
                $('.fancybox-thumb3').fancybox().trigger('click');
            }

        }
    });

    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        type: 'image',
        autoScale: true,
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }           
        }
    });

    $(".fancybox-thumb2").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });

    $(".fancybox-thumb3").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });

    $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            },
        },
        media : {

        }
    });
});
```

as for the code on the gallery beeing made is the next.

```
    <div>
    <?php 
    $dirImg = 'img/Galeria/folder 1';
    $fileImg = scandir($dirImg);
    ?>

    <?php foreach($fileImg as $image): ?>

        <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="img/Galeria/folder 1/<?php echo $image; ?>" title="">
        <img style="display: none;" src="img/Galeria/folder 1/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt=""></a>

    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php 
    $dirImg = 'img/Galeria/folder 2';
    $fileImg = scandir($dirImg);
    ?>

    <?php foreach($fileImg as $image): ?>

        <a class="fancybox-thumb2" rel="fancybox-thumb2" href="img/Galeria/folder 2/<?php echo $image; ?>">
        <img style="display: none;" src="img/Galeria/folder 2/<?php echo $image; ?>"></a>

    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php 
    $dirImg = 'img/Galeria/folder 3';
    $fileImg = scandir($dirImg);
    ?>

    <?php foreach($fileImg as $image): ?>

        <a class="fancybox-thumb3" rel="fancybox-thumb3" href="img/Galeria/folder 3/<?php echo $image; ?>">
        <img style="display: none;" src="img/Galeria/folder 3/<?php echo $image; ?>"></a>

    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I optimize the answer to use with any folders and images you want in diferent galleries. Down side is when you close the gallery you have to open the folders iframe again. Im working on looking how to make the folders iframe open when you close the gallery. Eitherway, here is the code I used. As you can see I returned the folder name and trim it so I can use it for a class of the fancybox. Hope this is better :D Ill leave the script and the HTML I used to make the galleries.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $("#defaultCountdown").countdown({until: new Date(2014, 3-1, 15)});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 400,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterClose  :   function() {
            var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

                $('.'+name.replace(/ /g,'')).fancybox({
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : ' none',

                    closeBtn  : true,
                    arrows    : true,
                    nextClick : true,

                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width  : 50,
                            height : 50
                        }
                    }
                }).eq(0).trigger('click');

        }
    });

    $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            },
        },
        media : {

        }
    });
});
```

Here is the code that makes the galleries.

```
    <?php
$cont = 0;
$dir    = 'img/Galeria';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
?>

<?php foreach($files1 as $file): ?>
    <?php if ($cont>1) { ?>

        <?php 
        $dirImg = 'img/Galeria/'.$file;
        $fileImg = scandir($dirImg);
        $cont = 0;
        ?>
        <div>
            <?php foreach($fileImg as $image): 
             if ($cont>2){?>

                <a class="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $file);?>" data-fancybox-group="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $file);?>" 
                    href="img/Galeria/<?php echo $file;?>/<?php echo $image; ?>" title=""></a>

            <?php } $cont++; endforeach ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
<?php $cont++; endforeach ?>
```

and here is what I used for the iframe where the folders are viewed.

```
<?php
    $cont = 0;
    $dir    = 'img/Galeria';
    $files1 = scandir($dir);

    ?>

    <div class="title"><h1>Folder de Imagenes</h1></div>
    <div class="folders">
        <ul class="gallery">

              <?php foreach($files1 as $file): ?>
                <?php if ($cont>1) { ?>
                  <li>

                        <a onclick="OnClickButton ('<?php echo $file;?>');" href="img/Galeria/<?php echo $file;?>">
                        <div class="folderImg"><img style="width: 100px;" src="img/folderImg.png"></div>
                        <div class="textFile"><h3><?php echo $file;?></h3></div>
                        </a>

                  </li>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php $cont++; endforeach ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: you could have used a single script for all your fancybox needs rather setting a different script for each selector (and repeating the same code over again.) What would happen if you would have 50 links? 50 fancybox init scripts? ... you patched your issue but I wouldn't recommend to follow this answer for other scenarios.

Comment: Each selection is calling a diferent preloaded fancybox folder galery. I see no way of joining all the scripts toghether

Comment: the way to do it is assigning a different `data-fancybox-group` to each gallery

Comment: But the $('.fancybox-thumb').fancybox.trigger('Click');  calls for the class or the data-fancybox-group??

Comment: you can always call the corresponding class selector using `.eq()`

Comment: What can I do to solve the problem when there are a lot of images in a folder. Its really heavy for the page to load all the images at start.

Comment: Well I made a little change @JFK, what do you think? Im kind of new to all this php and js. Trying my best to optimize the code.